# How can i insert or update jpa entity based on non unique key?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a Mysql table like below :

```
CREATE TABLE ABCD
(
  TId BIGINT(8) PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  TKey VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
  TValue BIGINT(8) NOT NULL
);
```

it has data like below :

```
TId TKey TValue 
1   abc    123
2   cde    345
3   def    546
```

What i want to do is , if i again insert entity with same TKey it'll update existing record instead of inserting new one.

Below is my code to save entity :

```
ABCD abcd = new ABCD();
abcd.setKey(key);
abcd.setValue(value);
abcdService.create(abcd);
```

Comment: This should be the default behavior for a Hibernate entity, I think.  What is wrong with your current Java code?

Comment: If i Set key -> cde and Value - > 789 , It'll insert new record.


`TId TKey TValue `


 `4    cde     789`.

What i want to do is it should update TId -> 2 with **789**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hibernate keeps tracks of entities in your Java code using the primary key column value.  So, if you create a new `ABCD` entity with the key `cde` and some value, Hibernate will this as a new entity, and when you save it will result in an insert into your underlying table.

If you want to instead *modify* the entity whose key is `cde`, then you should first fetch that record:

```
EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
ABCD movie = em.find(ABCD.class, 2);
movie.setValue(789);
```

The above assumes that your framework already handles transactions for you.

Comment: I want to find entity by Tkey like :


`ABCD movie = em.find(ABCD.class, 'cde');`


Because i have on TKey Param and i want to find entity with non primary key. is it possible?

Comment: You should usd either a JPA/HQL query for this, or a raw SQL query.  If you want to sift through all entities, you will need some sort of loop, and this is not the best way to do this.  The best way to do this is to let the database do the heavy lifting.